# Order of execution standardController and ExtensionController in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

one page has standard controller and extension controller that have save() function

when run page:

1. save() function of extension  will run only
2. save() function of standard  will run only
3. save() function of standard  will run first and after that is save() function of extension  will run
4. save() function of standard  will run first and after that is save() function of extension  will override.
5. save() function of extension  will run first and after that is save() function of standard  will run

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will only run the Save on the first extension it finds with the method name then it falls back to the std controller if not found.  If you want to run the standard save from the call the save method on the standard controller that you pass as an argument to the extension constructor.